# Jasmine test always passing

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I am running into some weird trouble while trying to write a basic jasmine test to ensure my server is doing what is expected. The server is a typical nodejs/express app.

```
var request = require('request');
var server = require("../src/js/server-app.js");
var url = "http://localhost:5000/";

describe("server", function() {
  it('succesfully GETs the front page', function() {
    request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(500);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

regardless of what I put in my expect (even expect(0).toBe(1)), my test passes and I'm having trouble figuring out why that is the case.

Thank you guys in advance for the help.

Comment: You didn't put the `done` argument in the callback to `it` so it is not treated as an asynchronous test, and your `request.get` callback does not fire.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I added the done into the it callback and I am entering the request.get callback now; however, It is saying that response is undefined. Is there something else wrong?

Comment: Yes, probably you are not starting your server and therefore `request.get` has an `error` (which you do not check) and no response -- most likeky `ECONNREFUSED`.  You may also want to check out https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, I was listening on the wrong port. Thank you for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use `done` as a callback, but you aren't specifying any arguments in `it`. Try the following:

```
it('successfully GETs the front page', function(done) {
  ...
  done();
}
```